# How to call xib viewcontroller from storyboard viewcontroller

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib

I am new to ios programming,I am having viewcontroller inside navigation controller in storyboard,in that viewcontroller i have tableview items,so onclick of item i have to present some viewcontroller which is xib viewcontroller,i tried with some code i am getting exception.

```
    code:

         -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
                ThirdController *detailViewController = [[ThirdController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdController" bundle:nil];

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

        }

exception:
SampleNaviationController[2499:84098] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ThirdController 0x7c02d9d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key sendResponse.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00b12a14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x005d3e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00b12631 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x002691bc -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x001c383a _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 115
    5   Foundation                          0x001c37bf -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 295
    6   UIKit                               0x0106506d -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 85
    7   Foundation                          0x001f801d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 384
    8   UIKit                               0x012d8cb4 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 132
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x005e800c -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00a42f51 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 273
    11  UIKit                               0x012d734e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2102
    12  UIKit                               0x0106cabc -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 429
    13  UIKit                               0x0106d4f4 -[UIViewController loadView] + 189
    14  UIKit                               0x0106d900 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 154
    15  UIKit                               0x01074406 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 114
    16  UIKit                               0x010975b9 -[UIViewController(UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods) beginAppearanceTransition:animated:] + 202
    17  UIKit                               0x010a99cc -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1389
    18  UIKit                               0x010bb769 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 803
    19  UIKit                               0x010bcada -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 68
    20  UIKit                               0x01298c4a -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 252
    21  UIKit                               0x00f6e008 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 810
    22  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x005e8059 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    23  QuartzCore                          0x0492680a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
    24  QuartzCore                          0x0491a4ee _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 388
    25  QuartzCore                          0x0491a352 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    26  QuartzCore                          0x0490ce8b _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 317
    27  QuartzCore                          0x04940e03 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 561
    28  QuartzCore                          0x04942674 _ZN2CA11Transaction17flush_transactionEv + 50
    29  UIKit                               0x00ed2dfa _afterCACommitHandler + 197
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00a2bffe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00a2bf5e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 398
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00a218dc __CFRunLoopRun + 1340
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00a210e6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00a20efb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x041c0664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x041c04a1 GSEventRun + 104
    37  UIKit                               0x00ea1bfa UIApplicationMain + 160
    38  SampleNaviationController           0x001017ba main + 138
    39  libdyld.dylib                       0x03184a21 start + 1
    40  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: We can't read your mind or see your computer. You have to tell us: _What_ exception are you getting?

Comment: So this has nothing to do with the code you showed. The problem is that your xib is improperly configured. It has a `sendResponse` outlet, but your ThirdViewController has no `sendResponse` property.

Comment: i understood ,i removed connection it is working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no `sendResponse` property in your ThirdViewController; hence the crash.

Here's my guess as to how that came about. When you configured the button in your xib, you made `sendResponse` an *outlet*. You probably wanted it to be an *action*.